# get columns from key words + count occurences

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a problem to solve. I need to create new columns from given `key_words` list and sum their occurrence in data frame.

key_words = ['apple', 'animal', 'everyone']

input data frame:

| id | description | xx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple is a healthy fruit. Everyone should eat it. | .. |
| 2 | Lion is a denagerous animal. | .. |
| 3 | Everyone likes him. | .. |

what I want to get:

| id | description | xx | apple | animal | everyone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple is a healthy fruit. Everyone should eat it. | .. | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Lion is a dangerous animal. | .. | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | Everyone likes him. | .. | 0 | 0 | 1 |

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you

```
key_words = ['apple', 'animal', 'everyone']
for key in key_words:
  df[key] = df['description'].str.lower().str.count(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ['apple', 'animal', 'everyone']
df['apple'], df['animal'], df['everyone']  = (
    zip(*list([len(re.findall(f'(?i){k}', r)) for k in keys] for r in df['description']))
)
```